# Android bluetooth send text

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have problem while sending messages from android to PC. Messages are send when i quit aplication on android or close socket. I can send messages from PC to android without problem. Should I always close connection and after that connect again?

```
public boolean sendData(String msg) {
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.getOutputStream().write(msg.getBytes());
            socket.getOutputStream().flush();
            //socket.getOutputStream().close();
            //socket.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            socket = null;
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was pc application problem. App was waiting for new line (\r\n).

Comment: Can you post here android and pc code pls ? Im trying to do the same, but i dont know well about. Thx much